# how to monitor a job from another job in talend open studio 5.3.1 version

Tags: talend

Hi i am beginer in Talend Open Studio 5.3.1 version.

currently i am facing issue in project i.e. schedule a job to run every 10 seconds and it monitor the other job and display output as status of another job which means the job is running or idle state.

Currently i am using Talend Open Studio 5.3.1 version by using this version it is possible or not .

explain  me how to schelude a job for 10 seconds and display output as status of another job.

can anyone suggest and  help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We should think a bit out of the box here. I'd solve this by using Project level logging: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataUserGuide520EN/2.6+Customizing+project+settings

You'll have the jobs status stored in a database table, you just have to check whether the last execution of the job is still running or not. (Self join the stats table)

Comment: Thsnks, Balazs Gunics but i am using Talend Open Studio Data Integration  5.3.1 Version but your solution is Talend OpenStudio forBigData so can u suggest how to do this issue in Talend 5.3.1 vesion

Comment: Have you checked your tool? Because I know it works with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring jobs is not supported in Talend Open Studio, but there is some workaround:

- Use a master job that launch the job to be monitored using [tRunJob](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tRunJob) component, and your master job will have an idea whats going on.
- Use empty files to synchronize your jobs, an empty file with a tricky name created by monitored jobs and the master job check them to get other jobs states.
- Much easier is to use [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/).